# Docker ASPNET Core container with Python installed

Tags: python-2.7, docker, asp.net-core, ironpython

I have an application that is running some processes and exposes them through WebAPI. Part of these processes need to execute Python scripts through the IronPython library. For this to happen though, Python 2.7 must also be installed on the system.

Has anyone solved this problem by figuring out how to install Python in the ASPNET Core Docker image (or by any other means). The only other hack I can think of it putting the Python executable into a dependency directory for the API.

Our current Docker File contents:

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:2.0
ARG source
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
COPY ${source:-obj/Docker/publish} .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Api.dll"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the RUN command to install it on the image.  Simply add the following to your Dockerfile.

The image I pulled from Dockerhub seemed to be running Debian Linux as the base OS so the following should work.  If it's another linux distro as the base in your instance, try [yum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yum_(.rpm)) instead or for windows OS chocolatey.

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:2.0
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install python2.7 -y
ARG source
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
COPY ${source:-obj/Docker/publish} .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "AIA.Vietnam.dll"]
```

Now the python executable should be available in /usr/bin/python2.7

Comment: `sudo` should not be required here, and it's best practice to combine `apt-get update` and `apt-get install` in a single line, to prevent the install from using an outdated package cache.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that.  Will update my answer to reflect your comments.

Comment: Thanks to both of you! I had to install sudo with the previous answer as well and I am still learning best practices (and a lot of other things).